# Webasyst изменить окончательную стоимость товара

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. **У меня используется старый Webasyst**, и у меня есть такая необходимость:

Я делаю скрытое поле в карточке товара  и значение которое там будет прописано мне нужно прибавить к конечной цене. Скажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Например:

Цена товара 10000 рублей.

на странице есть поле `<input type="hidden" name="my_add_price" value="3000">`

Что бы когда я нажал добавить в корзину, то в корзину попал товар с ценой 13000. Помогите пожалуйста, это очень нужно. Спасибо

Comment: Нет кода, нет как помочь